# Speed up WP_query with meta comparing dates

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

does anybody has any idea how to speed up this query

```
    $events_arr = array(
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 100,
            'orderby' => array( 'event_start' => 'ASC'),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_start',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'value'   => $queried_date,
                ),
               array(
                   'relation' => 'AND',
                   array(
                           'key' => 'event_end',
                           'compare' => '>=',
                           'value' => $queried_date,
                   ),
                   array(
                           'key' => 'event_start',
                           'compare' => '<',
                           'value' => $queried_date,
                   ),
                ),
            ),
);
```

Literally : **return events that starts today, or those that already begin but did not end yet.**

**In reality this query walks thru all events** and filter some of them out. The problem is that is painstakingly slow and will get worse in the future.

The ideal result would be if the query gets only the given number of events straight. Because now no matter how many or few events I want it always gets all and process them afterwards, or it seems like.
In my case it get always all actual 1700 events, each time.. (if we do not take take cache in to an account)

thanks for help

Comment: meta queries are very, very slow full stop, especially with comparisons. Have you considered a standard date query and using the post published date? You can use `pre_get_posts` filter to show both past and future posts not just those in the past

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade your hosting? I've had a very similar query running on AWS that is fine with 1700 events and meta_query that also had location.

Another option for you (if it's always the same query i.e. today as your queried date) is to use transients to store the result.

```
$events_arr = get_transient('events_running_today');

if (!$events_arr) {
    $expiration = 2 * 60 * 60; // time in seconds
    // run your existing query here
    $events_arr = // your query    
    set_transient( 'events_running_today', $events_arr, $expiration );
}
// etc etc
```

Comment: hi, yes it could be the hosting it self as it has still PHP 5.4.
I'l force the client to definitely upgrade. But that is not a the complete solution.

Cache: that is exactly what I'm doing now. I cache the query. Which is again not ideal solution.
thanks for helping me out.